# format response for api call back

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using php curl to receive data (ssl certificate) inspection but the data that comes back is one big lump of data in (according to firebug) it's in html format .. here is a sample of the output

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date: Mon, 13 Apr 2015 14:10:05 GMT 
Server: Apache 
Set-Cookie: v1st=9C74FC61F2FB5493; path=/; expires=Wed, 19 Feb 2020 14:28:00 GMT; domain=.geotrust.com 
Set-Cookie: v1st=9C74FC61F2FB5493; path=/; expires=Wed, 19 Feb 2020 14:28:00 GMT; domain=.geotrust.com 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.13 
Expires: Wed, 13 May 2015 14:10:05 GMT 
Vary: Accept-Encoding 
Cache-Control: max-age=604800, public 
Content-Type: text/html 

* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.geotrust.com/ 
* Hostname was found in DNS cache 
* Trying 69.58.181.102... 
* Connected to www.geotrust.com (69.58.181.102) port 443 (#0) 
* successfully set certificate verify locations: 
* CAfile: C:\xampp\htdocs\labs\test2\cacert.pem CApath: none 
* SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA 
* --- Certificate chain 
* 0 Subject: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware; C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; businessCategory=Private Organization; serialNumber=3479750; O=GeoTrust, Inc.; OU=Infrastructure Operations; CN=www.geotrust.com 
* Issuer: C=US; O=GeoTrust Inc.; CN=GeoTrust Extended Validation SHA256 SSL CA 
* Version: 3 (0x2) 
* Serial Number: 
* Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption 
* Start date: 2015-02-04 00:00:00 GMT 
* Expire date: 2017-02-03 23:59:59 GMT
```

It seems like each line is separated by a wildcard symbol `*` .. how can I cleanly output this data? currently i am just using

```
success: function (response) {
        $('#ajaxResponse').html(response);
```

Would be great if i could display certain data only but not sure how.

-- Here is the firebug --
[image]

Comment: What you're seeing there is the entire http response, headers and all. It's odd that you get it back formatted that way though.

Comment: updated post with screenshot of firebug

Comment: Output it inside a `<pre>...</pre>` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `<pre>` tag to indicate that it's pre-formatted.

```
$("#ajaxResponse").html('<pre>' + response + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to format it based on the assumption that they are separated by `*` then something like this might work for you:

```
$('#ajaxResponse').html(response.replace(/\*/g, '<br />'));
```

**EXAMPLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/mjgwcmnt/